# flexigrid get id of highlighted row

Tags: jquery, html

I understand this looks like a duplicate question, however its a bit different. I need to get back a value for an input contained in a table i can get the value for the row id but not for the input so any help would be brilliant. A cut down version of the table can be seen below. So how do i return the value for the checkbox on mouseeneter. Thank you.

```
   <table id="tblOrder" class="flexigrid autoht">
<tr id="row1081">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="proper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="OrderId[1081]" name="OrderId" value="1081"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr id="row1082">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="proper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="OrderId[1082]" name="OrderId" value="1082"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What i have tried so far is:

```
$('#tblOrder tr[id*="row"]').live('mouseenter', function(){



            console.log($('input[name="OrderId"]', '#tblOrder').val());


        });
```

Comment: Which question do you think is duplicate? Also, what's the code you've tried? Something like `$("tr").on("mouseenter", func...`?

Comment: Ive updated my question, i just noticed there is a lot of questions for getting the row id but this is a little different. Ive noticed that it only gets back the value of the first row and im unsure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the checked value (true, false) for the checkbox inside the table, if that's the case try http://jsfiddle.net/82gwa0cn/

```
$("tr input").on("mouseenter", function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

If you're trying to get the value of the checkbox try http://jsfiddle.net/82gwa0cn/1/

```
$("tr input").on("mouseenter", function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

So basically, bind to the mouseenter of input, not the tr.

Comment: I was after the value in the check box the orderId but i changed the fiddle and it works so thank you, this is what i was after [link](http://jsfiddle.net/82gwa0cn/).